# Can someone explain why global variable does not work in the second example?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

In the first example the code outputs 1. In the second example I get the error code: Local Variable 'x' referenced before assignment. Can anyone explain the reasoning for this?

Example 1:

```
def num():
    global x
    x = 1

def test():
    print(x)

num()        
test()
```

Exmaple 2:

```
def num():
    global x
    x = 1

def test():
    while x < 10:
        print(x)
        x+=1
num()
test()
```

Comment: `x` is a local variable for the `while` loop. You need to declare it as a `global` for that work as you expect.

Comment: Interesting... a little hard to wrap my head around but thank you for the information.

Comment: You have noticed the link to the duplicate above…?